# Conexión firebird con php servidor remoto

Tags: php, firebird, odbc

Trato de realizar una conexión a un servidor remoto con PHP a base de datos firebird:

```
$host = "190.121.XXX.XXX:3050:C:/TOC/PRUEBA/bd/P000_INFORMACION(PRUEBA).FDB";
$gestor_db = ibase_connect($host, "SYSDBA1","masterkey") or die(ibase_errmsg().' on line: '.__LINE__);
```

Pero al realizar pruebas obtengo el siguiente error:

> Unable to complete network request to host "190.121.XXX.XXX". Failed to establish a connection

Comment: ¿Esa IP no tiene que estar completa: `190.121.XXX.XXX`? o ¿el manejador de conexiones tiene capacidad de adivinarla?

Comment: Si la IP esta completa en el código, acá por ejemplo pongo las 3'x

Comment: Ok. ¿La ruta de tu BD es correcta: **`C:/TOC/PRUEBA/bd/P000_INFORMACION(PRUEBA).FDB`**? esos paréntesis en un nombre de bd no me gustan nada. ¿Puedes probar que la misma está corriendo bien, en el puerto **3050**? ¿El **firewall** no estará bloqueando el puerto 3050? ¿El nombre de usuario y contraseña has comprobado que son correctos? ¿La IP está registrada en el archivo `hosts`? [Ver esto](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq136/)

Comment: La base de datos conecta de forma correcta con la aplicación SQL Manager Lite for InterBase & Firebird, sin embargo al intentar conectarme mediante código obtengo el error anterior, cabe aclarar que estoy realizando la conexión desde hosting Godaddy, sin embargo ya fueron activados los componentes de interbase, firebird, odbc, pdo_firebird.

Answer (score 0):

Para la conexion a una base de datos en un servidor externo deberias poner la ruta de la siguiente manera:
ip:rutaenelservidor.
Por ejemplo en esta conexion accedo a la BD de aspel, que esta instalada en el disco D del servidor.

```
$host="192.168.1.100:D:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Aspel\Sistemas Aspel\SAE5.00\Empresa10\Datos\SAE5010.old.FDB"
```